# How to support heavy old alo vera?

Tags: plant-health, indoors, plant-care, tree-care

So I have managed to grow alo vera. Its fine but we cut its ‘leaf’ at times for various purposes. Now the plant has grown but its base is no longer supportive. This has caused the plant to lean towards one direction, and I am afraid one day it will fall with its own weight.

The question: should/can I put any support for the plant so it gets support and does not fall? Or I am overthinking it and should not worry about that?[image: The alo vera plant][image: the root]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvMUY6TNrR4

Comment: Thank you. I did get to know what I exactly wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvMUY6TNrR4), suggested by @black thumb, we can remove Alo Vera from its root, cut its visible roots and remove some of the older leafs and regrow it from there. Alo Vera would grow from there only.